# Error 1004 RemoveDuplicates

Tags: vba

Estoy tratando de eliminar duplicados en hoja, tomando solo en cuenta las columnas 10,14,26,28.
Utilicé grabar macros para sacar el código; el cual al ejecutarlo via Sub de prueba, me da error 1004.

Este es el código

```
Sub test()

    Columns("J:J").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AJ").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 14, 26, _
        28), Header:=xlYes



End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A:AJ").` Aquí estás seleccionando las columnas enteras de la hoja. Deberías seleccionar únicamente tu rango de datos, en plan `Range("A1:AJ100")`

Comment: hice el cambio y arroja el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que definir un rango (por ejemplo A1:J5000) y no seleccionarlo, que es lo que Elier te comentaba. Luego indicar qué columnas son las implicadas en la instrucción RemoveDuplicates:

```
    Sub QuitaDuplicados()
    
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  
  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
  Set Rng = sht.Range("A1:AJ" & sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row)

  Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 14, 26, 28), Header:=xlYes
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Modifiqué de la forma que comentas y ahora me arroja me arroja error 5, "argumento o llamada de procedimiento no valida"

Comment: Qué línea te marca error? Ese Sub lo acabo de probar en mi equipo con Excel 2016 de 64bits y no tira ningún error.

Comment: Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 14, 26, 28), Header:=xlYes

Comment: Tienes más código junto a esa línea? Edita tu primer post y pon ahí todo el código que tengas para poder analizarlo al completo.

Comment: En el primer post se encuentra el código completo, te puedo enviar el archivo a algún correo.

Comment: A ver, el código de tu primer post está mal. Si sigues poniendo "Columns("J:J").Select" seguirá estando mal. Utiliza únicamente el código que he puesto yo y sustituye todo tú código por lo que te pongo yo.

Comment: Estimado, hago exactamente eso y da error 1004

Comment: Sube tu fichero en algún sitio para que podamos descargarlo y echarle un vistazo.
¿Qué SO tienes? Es un PC? Un MAC?

Comment: Estoy trabajando desde un PC, con Windows 10 Pro, y el producto de office es 365 para empresas, dejo link de descarga:      http://uploaded.net/file/jf85s85m

Comment: Luego probaré con tu fichero. Podría ser que si estás trabajando con tablas o tablas dinámicas haya que definir bien el rango de datos y no presuponer que tienen 5000 filas. Luego hago un par de pruebas y te comento.

Answer (score -1):

estuve probando y así no me da error:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AJ").select
selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 14, 26, _
        28), Header:=xlYes
```

Espero te sirva
Jorge